# current month values in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, date

how to get current month to date values in oracle 12c sql developer

```
Select dcc.EMPLOYEECODE, dcc.DUTYID, dtt.DUTYDESC 
from DUTYCHART dcc
  join DCDUTYCHART dtt 
   on dcc.RESTCODE = dtt.RESTCODE 
  and dcc.DUTYID = dtt.DUTYID
  and trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Here am getting current date but I want to show current month and previous month, I tried some functions like add-months but it didn't worked for me

Comment: . . Please show samples of your data (as a *text table*).  And include the data types of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') -- CURRENT MONTH START DATE

ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), -1) -- PREVIOS MONTH START DATE
```

If you want to get data of previous month then your query's where clause must include: Replace `(trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate))` with one of the following according to your need

```
trunc(date) BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), -1)
AND trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') - 1 -- PREVIOUS MONTH'S DATA

trunc(date) >= trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') -- -- CURRENT MONTH'S DATA

trunc(date) >= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), -1) -- PREVIOUS AND CURRENT MONTH'S DATA TOGETHER
```

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks Tejash for response,, it's really worked for me but when im applying trunc(date) >= trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH')  or  trunc(date) >= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), -1). it's showing current today date only not for month to date.

Answer (score 0):

For the current month, use:

```
date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH')
```

For the previous month, use:

```
(date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') - interval '1' month and
 date < trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH')
)
```

There is no reason to truncate `date` for the comparison.

Comment: thanks Gordon, but it's still showing today date data only instead of month to date.